# Why aren't my CSS and JS files loading when deployed?

Tags: ajax, vb.net, jquery

When I run my VB.Net, AJAX-enabled application in Visual Studio, it works exactly how I want it to, but when I deploy it to the server, the site only displays the asp tags translated into HTML. There are no css or js files loading. The same issue occurs with a blank web application started in Visual Studio 2012. It runs fine through Visual Studio, but when it is deployed to the server, it does not have any styling or Javascript. I know the server has .Net 4.5, which is the version I used, but it also has SharePoint and I've heard that Sharepoint is only compatible with 3.5. (Is this true?) How can I get this application running correctly on the server? I am willing to provide code samples, but I'm not sure which code to show. Let me know what you need to see.

I have tried the following:

- Removing all references to ScriptManager (replacing with Page.ClientScript, however, that just caused more issues)
- checked that all necessary references to AJAX exist
- a myriad of edits to Web.Config

Edit:
It is an older version of Sharepoint run on a Windows Small Business Server 2008 SP2. IIS recognizes version 4.0 (this means 4.5 is okay too right?) of .Net. I have now also tried:

- verifying that the 4.0 is registered in IIS (I haven't checked if 4.5 is registered because I don't know if it's necessary and we couldn't find the file to register it).
- building it to target x64
- removing the database connection set up in Server Explorer and rebuilding (currently waiting for this deployment)

Comment: The minimum framework requirement for SharePoint 2013 is [4.5](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx). SharePoint 2010 targets [3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231582.aspx).

Comment: Check the browser developer console to see if there are load errors.  Odds are there is a problem with the relative path being used to load scripts/css.

Comment: It looks like you're right. I think there is a problem with the path. Would that prevent it from loading my VB.Net code as well?

Answer (score 0):

My business had a consultant with more experience with deployments come in to help me and the server admin get this deployed. I had been able to fix most of the path issues, but there were 2 remaining files that it couldn't find. The consultant was able to trace them to the .Net bundler.

The problem was with the bundling provided in .Net 4.5. The files written by the bundler couldn't be seen by the html when loading. We commented out the bundling code and directly included the files we needed and have the site up and running. I would eventually like to get bundling back into the project, but will be waiting at least until I have a bug fix to deploy.